# Web form submission not entering into database

Tags: java, mysql, sql, forms

my web form submission (used html file in sublime text to make form) has not been entering into my sql database after I decided to add an ID column inside my actual data table. It was my understanding that you do not have to input the ID in the values bracket, since it does it automatically. Does anyone know why this is happening? And how I can fix it?  Thanks so much in advance. I'm a newb.

Comment: I added the Java tag to your question.  In case I did this in error, feel free to remove it.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen thanks! :)

Comment: Are you sure, in your MySQL database, the user `root` does not have a password? Please write `e.printStackTrace();` inside the `catch` block and share us Exception trace that you are getting.

Comment: Don't post your database credentials in a public forum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide a value for the `ID` column, even if it be autoincrement.  From the MySQL [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert.html):

> If you do not specify a list of column names for INSERT ... VALUES or INSERT ... SELECT, values for every column in the table must be provided by the VALUES list or the SELECT statement.

Assuming your `person` table has the following column order

```
person (ID, name, birthday, address, gender, school)
```

then your `INSERT` should take the form:

```
stmt.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO person VALUES (null, " + "'
            + name + "','" + bday + "','" + address + "',   '"
            + gender + "','" + school + "')");
```

Here I am passing `null` as the value of the `ID` column, to which MySQL will assign an autoincrement value.

Note that you should consider using prepared statements as they will protect against SQL injection and will also make your query easier to read.

Comment: Ok, will do! Thanks for your time!